# In Jena API, How to count how many individuals of a class using Jena RULE?

Tags: jena, ontology

I want to get how many individuals of a class. For example, for the Person class, there is A, B, C. I tried to count it using the following rule:

```
[r3: (?p rdf:type hv:Person),(?classx1 hv:hasvalue ?n),addOne(?n,?new)
-> drop(1),(?class1 hv:hasvalue ?new)
]
```

However, it was fired in a closed loop since the `(?class1 hv:hasvalue ?new)` will change each time. I dont like to introduce SPARQL.

Comment: Even if this can be achieved with a rule, it is likely to be extremely inefficient. Why do you not want to use SPARQL, which is the most intuitive and efficient way to achieve exactly what you need?

Comment: Thank you! I want to design a continous reasoning system. If I use SPARQL, I have to determine when to run SPARQL dynamically. So, I want to use rule only. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your rule...what's the purpose of the ` (?p rdf:type hv:Person)` clause? `?p` is bound nowhere else in the rule.

Comment: And Jena rules are monotonic - you'll never be able to remove/replace existing facts.

Comment: Thank you AKSW, I realized that I asked a wrong question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What I do to count individuals is :

```
OntModel model;

Resource individual = model.getResource("http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"));
Property property = model.getProperty("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type");

ResIterator iterator = infModel.listResourcesWithProperty(property, individual) ;

int count = Iterators.size(iterator);
```

Last line is possible because of [Guava Library](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html).

It can be improved but still a solution.

More information and corrections in the comments. Thanks to @ssz.

Comment: This answer does not apply to the Jena Rules, and is not entirely correct, since `owl:NamedIndividual` means that source ontology is an OWL2 ontology. `org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel`, mentioned in the answer, does not support OWL2. Moreover OWL (both 1 and 2) supports anonymous individuals, which have no `rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual` declarations and therefore can not be listed such way. Also the question is about class-individual relationship, not for all individuals in the model.

Comment: To list individuals for a class there is a `org.apache.jena.ontology.OntClass#listIndividuals` method, which should work correctly for OWL2 also. As an option, to list all individuals in the model, the another jena-based solution can be chosen - [OntGraphModel](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/avicomp/ontapi/jena/model/OntGraphModel.java), it is strictly for OWL2, so it is taking into account things, not supported in the standard jena ont model.